# Flutter: Unit testing Firebase Firestore through Repository

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-test

I have a purpose to test my Firestore repository methods. I found out a useful [fake_cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/fake_cloud_firestore) package, which helps to mock firestore.

I have a repository method that I want to test:

```
@override
  Future<Either<UserFailure, UserDTO>> updateUser(FUser user) async {
    try {
      final UserDTO userDTO = UserDTO.fromDomainForUpdatingProfile(user);

      final Map<String, dynamic> userJson = userDTO.toJson();

      await _firestore
          .collection(FirestoreCollections.COLLECTION_USERS)
          .doc(user.id)
          .set(userJson, SetOptions(merge: true));

      return right(userDTO);
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (e.message!.contains('PERMISSION_DENIED')) {
        return left(const UserFailure.insufficientPermission());
      } else {
        return left(const UserFailure.unexpected());
      }
    } on Exception {
      return left(const UserFailure.unexpected());
    }
  }
```

And a test:

```
test('exception test', () async {
        final Map<String, dynamic> jsonMap = json.decode(
          fixture("user/full_domain_fuser.json"),
        );

        final FUser fuser = FUser.fromJson(jsonMap);
        final userJson = UserDTO.fromDomainForUpdatingProfile(fuser).toJson();

        when(fakeFirebaseFirestore
                .collection(FirestoreCollections.COLLECTION_USERS)
                .doc(fuser.id)
                .set(userJson, SetOptions(merge: true)))
            .thenThrow(Exception());

        final result = await userRepository.updateUser(fuser);

        expect(result, const Left(UserFailure));
      });
    });
```

What I want to do is throw an Exception when calling Firestore and updating the document, but when() part is not being triggered. When running a test I get:

```
Bad state: No method stub was called from within `when()`. Was a real method called, or perhaps an extension method?
```

FakeFirebaseFirestore and UserRepository construction:

```
FakeFirebaseFirestore fakeFirebaseFirestore = FakeFirebaseFirestore();
UserRepository userRepository = UserRepository(fakeFirebaseFirestore);
```

It looks like that my firestore call looks the same in a test and also in repository method. What am I missing in this when() part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is coming up because you're using an object that does not extend the [Mock](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/Mock-class.html) class from the [mockito](https://pub.dev/packages/mockito) package where the [when](https://pub.dev/documentation/mockito/latest/mockito/when.html) function comes from.

You can write the `Firestore` logic in a separate util class and mock that class and test against that.